# fastest algorithm to check if nth root is irrational

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there an efficient algorithm to check if the nth root of a number is irrational or not? This would obviously need to work for any integer value of n, but it needs to work when the input is a floating-point number e.g. cube root of 3.375 is 1.5.

Edit: this is for a simplification algorithm, which simplifies maths expressions, so `125^(1/3)` is simplified to `5` but `28^(1/3)` is left as it is.

Answers preferably in Rust would be great (though I need it to work with a bignumber library).

Comment: You could convert to exponential representation, then divide the angle by n and check whether it is a multiple of Pi.

Comment: Maybe use [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to get a lower and upper bound of the root?

Comment: What is a floating point number for you? A mathematical real number or a number represented in a computer as a float of double?

Comment: A possibility: using continuous fraction decomposition, it is easy and fast to get 3.375=27/8. Then prime decomposition of numerator and denominator will help too

Comment: The nth root of an integer is either an integer, or an irrational. The nth root of a rational `a/b` given in irreducible form is rational iff the nth roots of a and b are both integers. Please note that there is no general representation of real numbers; a "floating-point" representation of a number is a quotient `a / 2^m` with integer a and nonnegative integer `m`, which obviously is rational. Numbers which cannot be represented exactly as `a / 2^m` are approximated.

Comment: How is this number provided to you? It might help to provide examples of what you're trying to do in code, using whatever programming language you're targeting. There are too many unknowns with the question as it stands, and we're left guessing what you really want to do. An example would help pin things down. Some context would be really useful, too.

Comment: Does "number" mean "integer?" Rational number represented exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a simplification algorithm and not a general algorithm then it's probably good enough to do something like (pseudo code):

```
input = "28^(1/3)" # input is text or something
value = evaluate(input) # Custom method to convert input to float/decimal
value_as_integer = value.floor.to_integer
if value_as_integer equals value
then return value_as_integer.to_string 
else return input
```